# compare string variables with php

Tags: php, string, compare

I try to figure out how to solve the following issue

```
$str = 'asus company';
$brands = "asus|lenovo|dell";
```

Than I would like to compare the 2 string variables and retrieve the matching sub string. The desired output would be `'asus'`.

I know that I can use `strtr` function from php but this one returns just a boolean. I need the string as well.

Comment: Will your string be always the same format? If so I suggest you parse both the string using ` ` and `|` and keep it as array. After that you can easily use `in_array()` to check for the match.

Comment: See Jari's answer for a fast way and simple way if you allways have the same '|' seperated list of brands. If you want to find the matching patterns in the strings in general you can use a suffix tree.

Comment: yes the brands are going to have the same format. I'm going to give a try with Jaris tip.

Comment: I replied late, but have a look to my solution if you think that the $str could have commas or other stuff xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$str` is separated by a space and `$brands` by a pipe, this should work:

```
<?php

$str = 'asus company';
$brands = "asus|lenovo|dell";

$array_str = explode(' ', $str);
$array_brands = explode('|', $brands);

var_dump(
    array_intersect($array_str, $array_brands)
);
```

The output is

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "asus"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` will do the work for you. Just remember that your regular expression has to be correct, meaning that in your case simple `|` delimiter is enough.

```
$str = 'asus company'; 
$brands = "asus|lenovo|dell"; 

preg_match("/($brands)/", $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1] ;
```

`$matches` contains occurences of the keywords. `$matches[0]` has the full string and `$matches[1]` has the first occurence and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is What I would Do:

```
$str = 'asus company';
$brands = "asus|lenovo|dell";

//Finding every single word (separated by spaces or symbols) and putting them into $words array;
preg_match_all('/\b\w+\b/', $str, $words);

//Setting up the REGEX pattern;
$pattern = implode('|', $words[0]);
$pattern = "/$pattern/i";

//Converting brands to an array to search with
$array = explode('|', $brands);

//Searching 
$matches = preg_grep($pattern, $array);
```

---

You face several problems there: If the string has commas or other symbols, then we can't just use explode to separate, that's why I used a preg_match all to separate them and set up a pattern.

With preg_grep you will avoid upper/lower case problems.

---

You can also `array_intersect($words, $array)` there as @Znarkus responded, instead of setting up a pattern and `preg_grep()`, but make sure you `strtolower()` `$brands` and `$str` before converting to array, I'm not sure if array_intersect() is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you may use like below

```
$array1 = explode(" ",$str);
$array2 = explode("|",$brands);
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```